# Do Web Workers Increase (or Decrease) Security?

Tags: javascript, security, web-worker, browser-security

Do web workers alleviate or intensify any of JavaScript's and the Browser Environment's known security issues?

Comment: What "known security issues"? What's the specific problem you face?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I am considering using web workers and would like to know if they bring any added security risk, or if I get some security enhancements for free.

Comment: Web workers are basically very limited threads. There aren't really any security implications one way or another.

Comment: Please avoid "the title says it all". Also, I second George Stocker.

Comment: Why do you think it may or may not?

Comment: The same issues that apply to broken js engine sandboxing, apply to web workers that's it, so if you are using js already there is no new attack surface added to your app. (But that's something new and not tested, as always security bugs are possible :) )

Answer (score 6):

According to the Mozilla Web Workers Security Review:

- Workers execute in a tightly controlled sandbox.
- No access to Components or other global JS components.
- Only basic JS (Math, Date, etc.), timeouts, XHR, and importScripts.
- Script loading is subject to the same restrictions as on the main
  thread (content policies, same origin restrictions, etc.).
- XHR uses the same code as the main thread.

These answered all the security considerations I had.

Comment: A list of APIs are available here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers Be aware that IndexedDB is listed, so malicious code in a worker could edit/delete data. More discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26488003