# Evaluating JavaScript expression with a worker

Tags: javascript, evaluation

I need to evaluate JavaScript expressions, in a browser, Chrome. To make it safe, I use a `Blob` and a `Worker` running my evaluator, until it posts back the result of a timeout cancels the wait. This is working fine. I also need to support an environment for my JavaScript. I do this as below:

```
function evalWorker () {
  let postResponse = function(expr, ...) {
    let presets = `var EnvObject = {};
                EnvObject.platform = "Chrome";
                EnvObject.pasteboard = "${clipboard}";
                EnvObject.baseDate = new Date();
                ...
                EnvObject._output = "";
                EnvObject.appendOutput = (str) => {EnvObject._output += str; };
                `
    postMessage(eval(presets + expr));
  };
  onmessage = function(e) {
    postResponse(e.data['expression'], e.data['clipboard'], ...);
  }
}
```

My problem is that if `_output` is not empty, I need to return that - `_output` instead of the evaluated expression, as in

```
EnvObject.appendOutput('hello');
var a = 0;
++a;
```

Should return `hello`; while without `appendOutput`, it should return `1`.

How would I go about something like this?

Comment: `postMessage(selectValue(eval(expr), EnvObject._output))`?

Comment: Evaluating arbitrary code in a worker is not safe at all. What makes you think the code is run in a sandboxed environment?

Comment: EnvObject lives within the expression, right? It would be `undefined`.

Comment: why would worker running in a blob be unsafe?

Comment: @MosheShmukler What are you trying to defend against? https://stackoverflow.com/q/16600607/1048572

Comment: @MosheShmukler No, `EnvObject` does not "live within the expression". It either lives in the global scope or in the local scope of `postResponse`, it should in any case be available there.

Comment: @MosheShmukler It can make same origin requests, modify your local storage and probably even cookies. Think of workers as a separate thread that has access to everything except the DOM.

Comment: @Bergi you are wrong. `EnvObject` is not going to be defined anywhere outside the expression being evaluated. As far as `postResponse()` aware `EnvObject` is text.
@Derek朕會功夫 `Blob`/`Worker` provide safety from damaging the executing process. That works for me. Let me know if you have ideas regarding my question.

Comment: @MosheShmukler Ah, in strict mode the `eval` creates its own scope. So either use global eval, or sloppy mode, or simply declare `var EnvObject` before the `eval` call in the function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bergi had the right idea with pushing the scope out. The below works.

```
function evalWorker () {
  let postResponse = function(expr, TextExpander) {
    let result = eval(expr);
    if (EnvObject._output && EnvObject._output.length) {
      postMessage(EnvObject._output);
    } else {
      postMessage(result);
    }
  };
  onmessage = function(e) {
    var EnvObject = {};
    EnvObject.platform = "Chrome";
    EnvObject.pasteboardText = e.data['clipboard'];
    ...
    EnvObject._output = "";
    EnvObject.appendOutput = function(str) {EnvObject._output += str; };
    postResponse(e.data['expression'], EnvObject);
  }
}
```